# Почему, имея массив из 5 чисел, получаем 6-е?

Tags: php

```
$arr='12345';
$arr[$arr[4]]='1';
```

Почему при выводе становится 123451, а если ставить

```
$arr[$arr[4]]='12';
```

то все равно результат 123451?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Синтаксис обращения к элементам строки подобно массивам, конечно, допустим, но вот данная конкретная форма а) неочевидно идентифицирует переменную как строку, б) считается устаревшей. Новый синтаксис для обращения к элементу строки:

```
$str = "12345";
print $str{4};
```

2) Увас появляется 5-й элемент потому, что $arr[4] возвращает подстроку '5', и далее в $arr['5'] устанавливается строка '1'. Преобразование символов в числа - отдельная тема.

3) Когда вы пытаетесь вставить в единичный элемент строки более, чем 1 символ, вставляется первый.

Посмотреть как пример работает в реале: [онлайн-интерпретатор на eval.in](https://eval.in/209861)

Answer (score 1):

Ничего себе ты массивы чисел создаешь, строкой? Строка - это не массив. А ты работаешь со строкой:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$arr[$arr[4]]=8;
```

Comment: А мне понравилась такая работа с массивом. ))

Answer (score -1):

Строка - это массив, но не такой массив, как массив. Хотя бы потому, что в строке символ может быть представлен последовательностью от 1 до 4 байт. Если вы пишите `$arr[4]`, то какой именно байт подраузмеваете (без учета, что цифры однобайтовые)? В общем, так не делают. Для строк и символов свои функции, для массивов - свои.

Ну, хорошо, сделайте теперь с `$arr - foreach()`.